# Create a logoff script/task for Windows

Tags: windows, script

***Without*** using AD GPOs (Active Directory Group Policy Objects), or similar, how would one go about creating a logoff script for Windows?

This would be for XP (home and pro), Vista, and 7, in a personal environment (ie, no Domain Controllers anywhere in sight).

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: yes - XP, Vista, and 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Run box type `gpedit.msc` and hit enter.  This will open the Group Policy editor.  This will allow you to edit the kind of things normally managed by an AD Policy directly on the local machine.

[image]

Under **Windows Settings** there is a **Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)** option where you can specify Startup and Shutdown scripts.

Comment: you can use GPs without AD? I did not know that

Comment: Essentially all a GP does is update some Registry Keys.  This tool allows you to edit the same keys directly.

Comment: `gpedit.msc` is not available on XP Home (haven't looked on my Pro box yet)

Comment: it's available on my XP Pro box.  probably would work fine if you copy the file over to the XP Home box.

Comment: +1 for including a screenshot of the right way to do this

Comment: does that continue to work for Vista and 7?

Comment: @warren - It worked on my Windows 7 RC system.  I don't have a Vista system to try it on but I presume so.

Comment: cool - looks like the best available route

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP Pro, you can assign startup and shutdown scripts (i.e. batch files) using Group Policy. Open the Help And Support Center and search on 'shutdown script'.

Comment: -1: warren said "Without using AD GPOs", so no Group Policy!

Comment: @snark: as the other answer suggests, `gpedit.msc` works fine in the absence of AD.

Answer (score 0):

The two previous answers explain how to execute scripts on startup/shutdown.

The answer to the actual question asked (logon/logoff) is to create a windows task scheduler task where you tie the trigger to be "On connect/disconnect from user session" instead of a more familiar scheduled time or date.

Run taskschd.msc --> create task --> Triggers --> New --> "On connection to user session" ...

Comment: it would *seem*, though perhaps I'm mistaken, that this would run even if all you did was disconnect (but **NOT** logoff) from an RDP session and then reconnected later