# Create a logoff script/task for Linux

Tags: linux, script

In similar vein to my question for [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/65456/create-a-logoff-script-task-for-windows) and [Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/65458/create-a-logoff-script-task-for-mac-os-x), how would one go about creating a logoff script for Linux?

Any distro is fine, as I'm sure it'd be extendable across others. I'm most familiar with RHEL/CentOS/Fedora and Ubuntu, though.

**addition**
If this exists for both a graphical login (ie at a lcoal workstation) and for a remote login (such as via `ssh`), that'd be ideal - but I'd settle for one or the other if both aren't possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For remote SSH sessions, it's the job of your shell to handle any on-logout scripting.  The Bash shell typically runs `~/.bash_logout`.

For X sessions, the login manager controls on-logout scripting.  File locations depend on which login manager is in use.  The Xserver is not running when the on-logout script is executed, so don't include any programs in the script that try to access the display.

- [For Gnome](http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en), use `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` for a system-wide default logout script (runs no matter who's logging out).  Unlike Bash's logout script, I don't think there's a user-specific version of a GDM PostSession script.
- XDM uses a Reset script is installed to `/etc/X11/xdm/Xreset`.
- [For KDE (using KDM)](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-workspace/kdm/index.html), you want [the `Reset` script](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-workspace/kdm/kdm-scripts.html#kdmrc-xreset).  KDE3 uses `/etc/kde3/kdm/Xreset`.  The location may be specified in KDM's configuration file, `/etc/kde3/kdm/kdmrc`, with the `Reset` key.
- [WDM](http://voins.program.ru/wdm/) apparently uses a pair of Reset scripts: a per-display script at `/etc/X11/wdm/Xreset_0` (for display `:0`), and a global script at `/etc/X11/wdm/Xreset`.  The WDM configuration file is in `/etc/X11/wdm/wdm-config`.

The file locations in this answer are from Debian packages.  Ubuntu packages will generally use the same files, but other distributions may use alternate locations.

Comment: is there a similar feature for KDE or fluxbox or icewm?

Comment: GDM is the Gnome-replacement for XDM, the X login manager.  KDE's is KDM, i believe.  there are others but those are the big three.  i think WDM is often recommended for use with fluxbox?  there's also SDM (SSH-based!) which probably provides scripting support.  don't know more details; if i get a chance later i'll try to find out.

Answer (score 6):

If the distro uses PAM to authentificate users, you can install [`pam_script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/pam-script.7.html) to provide `onsessionopen/onsessionclose` funcionality.

I use it in Debian based distros to check files modified by users thru `scp` only and adjust the files' permissions.

You can [download `pam_script` from freecode](http://freecode.com/projects/pam_script).

Answer (score 5):

The C-shell, a.k.a. csh, has the .logout functionality, and Bash (the more current default) has .bash_logout, but I don't remember any other shells (ksh, sh, etc) with a similar concept.