# Linux - reset user settings on every login

Tags: linux, multiple-users

I would like to install a Linux machine (latest Linux Mint Debian Edition) as a shared computer for multiple users. All of the users should share one account with the same password.

Think of it as a classroom PC or a Kiosk PC

After every login - all prior bookmarks/user settings should be reset to a default.

Is there a good documentation/tutorial/blog entry (from your prior experience) available for this?

Comment: I found an article in a german tech magazine (http://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/Der-oeffentliche-PC-1168000.html) which covers this. Unfortunately - it is in german (which is OK for me) and payed content :P. The author suggests a Union Filesystem, a GDM PostLogin/PostSession hookscript (simple) and a Grub Password. This would do it for me - but maybe there are english resources available for the non-german interested ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article in a german tech magazine (heise.de/ct/artikel/Der-oeffentliche-PC-1168000.html) which covers this. Unfortunately - it is in german (which is OK for me) and payed content :P. The author suggests a Union Filesystem, a GDM PostLogin/PostSession hookscript (simple) and a Grub Password.

Unfortunatly I could not find any good english documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to put entries in something like /etc/profile to remove everything in the home directory.

Comment: There should be a better way.. something like how live cds work, but for logoff and for user files..

Comment: This would create to many side effects and pitfalls. What if the user opens a shell - what if another user logs in with ssh etc. I guess I am looking for more complex tutorial - where all the pitfalls have been discovered already ;)

Comment: the file in /etc/profile is read ONLY by login shells, not ordinary shells, and it is not writeable. Therefore it is safe.

Answer (score 1):

If all the users share one account with the same password, then you need one login which is associated with one home directory.  For example: '/home/user'.  You need to clear this home directory for every login event.  You can write a script to clear this home directory and run it by writing a command in .bashrc inside '/home/user'.

Comment: That's true - but the user could alter this file and destroy my precious script. Also: As far as I know .bashrc .profile etc are read when you open a terminal. So if I open xterm as user "user" - than all of the files would be deleted, right?

Comment: As it is a shared access, chances will be there that the user deletes this script.  You need to keep a backup in /root and you can place an automatic check, to see, if the file is missing, it should be copied automatically.

Answer (score 1):

make a daemon (while true) which checks every 2 sec or so if the user is logged in. if he's not and the home dir is not empty, then it will clear the home

Answer (score 1):

It should also be possible to control this type of activity from `/etc/profile` which is read before the `/home/user/.profile` and is owned by root. (See: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Startup_scripts).

However, this would not prevent the issue of opening up another xterm or a second user logging in at the same time. If the system is not multi-user, i.e. there is only one user active at a time, then you should be able to get the desired effects of clearing the home directory by using `.bash_logout`. (see: [Create a logoff script/task for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/65460/create-a-logoff-script-task-for-linux))

To ensure that users don't edit these files make sure that they do not have access to `chown` and `chmod`. If they do not have access to these commands and the file has some restrictive permissions set say `0440` and is owned by a different user, then the files should be secure enough to prevent tampering.