# Keep GnuPG credentials cached for entire user session

Tags: cache, authentication, gnupg

GnuPG can, with `gpg-agent`, cache access to a private key. How can I **keep that cache active for the entire user session**?

When I unlock the key for `gpg-agent`, it only stays cached for a limited time. With SSH's agent, I enter the passphrase one time and it stays cached for the whole session. I want the same behaviour from `gpg-agent`.

So, `ssh-agent` doesn't suffer from a limited cache lifetime. But `gpg-agent` limits the cache lifetime, at least by default. How can I **eliminate the limit on cache time** from `gpg-agent`?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The user configuration (in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`) can only define the default and maximum caching duration; it can't be disabled.

The `default-cache-ttl` option sets the timeout (in seconds) after the last GnuPG activity (so it resets if you use it), the `max-cache-ttl` option set the timespan (in seconds) it caches after entering your password. The default value is 600 seconds (10 minutes) for `default-cache-ttl` and 7200 seconds (2 hours) for `max-cache-ttl`.

Set it to a year or so – say, `34560000` seconds (400 days) – and you should be fine:

### GnuPG 2.1 and above

In GnuPG 2.1 and above, the `maximum-cache-ttl` option was renamed to `max-cache-ttl` without further changes.

```
default-cache-ttl 34560000
max-cache-ttl 34560000
```

### GnuPG 2 and below

```
default-cache-ttl 34560000
maximum-cache-ttl 34560000
```

### Restart the agent

But for this change to take effect, you need to end the session by restarting gpg-agent.

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
gpg-agent --daemon --use-standard-socket
```

If you want to limit to your session length, you'd need to kill the daemon at logout. This is very different between operating systems, so I'm referring to another question/answer containing [hints for different systems](https://superuser.com/questions/65460/create-a-logoff-script-task-for-linux).

You could also restart the `gpg-agent` during login, but this does not limit caching time to the session length, but logins of a user. Decide yourself if this is a problem in your case.

Comment: Is this a “you can't do what you're asking” response? It's not clear, since you're talking about limiting the session length or limiting caching time. I want exactly the opposite of that: no arbitrary limit on the cache time or session length.

Comment: Kind of that, you can only workaround by setting a rather huge ttl. Set it to a year or so and you should be fine - but need to end the session by restarting `gpg-agent`.

Comment: Please note that in latests versions (at least gnupg 2.1), the `maximum-cache-ttl` option doesn't exist. To see the correct options, see the official documentation: https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html#Agent-Options

Comment: At least in GnuPG 2.1 the default for `default-cache-ttl` is 600 seconds (10 minutes), not two hours.

Comment: @jlh Looking at the man pages for different versions of `gpg-agent`, the correct value seems to be 10 minutes for all releases. I edited the answer, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: What can the reason be that my GPG4Win asks every 10 minutes even that my settings are set to the samples above? `max-cache-ttl 34560000`

Comment: This sounds like you used the wrong file for setting up the value. I'm sorry I'm not deep enough into Windows to immediately being able to tell you how to best debug this, but I'd start with setting the `log-file` option -- if nothing is logged to that file, you're indeed probably using the wrong file.

Comment: @Ben I think I found the answer to this. You have to put the `gpg-agent.conf` file at `$env:AppData\gnupg`

I did this and it all seems to be working the way I want...

Comment: @CubanX already have this, but this wont work for me...

Comment: Ugh, sorry @Ben. It has worked for everyone that has tried it in our office...

I wonder what is different about your set up?

Comment: I think this should use "max-cache-ttl", since the "maximum-cache-ttl" option does not exists (in gnupg 2.1). I'd fix this as a typo, but I'm not sure if it maybe does exist in other versions?

Comment: Found it helpful to know how to check `gpg-agent` has picked up my config changes `gpgconf --list-options gpg-agent | grep cache-ttl`.  Restarting the agent `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`

Comment: ```gpg-agent[34573]: WARNING: "--use-standard-socket" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent[34574]: gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.3.6 started```

Comment: Really? they did a breaking change so that they could change the name of the config option from "maximum" to "max"?

Answer (score 39):

## For Windows

The file you need to edit should be placed at: `~\.gnupg\`

If you run that in a PowerShell window it will open: `C:\Users\<UserName>\.gnupg`

Just put the `gpg-agent.conf` file there with whatever values you like.

You can verify it took by running:

1. `gpgconf.exe --reload gpg-agent`
2. `gpgconf.exe --list-options gpg-agent`

You can also use this one liner:
`Set-Content -Path ~\.gnupg\gpg-agent.conf -Value "default-cache-ttl 86400$([System.Environment]::NewLine)max-cache-ttl 86400"`

### Older Versions Of GPG

In older versions, the file was at:
`$env:AppData\gnupg` (`C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\gnupg`)

So if you can't find it at `~\.gnupg\gpg-agent.conf` look there.

Comment: If a second answer here isn't appropriate we can move this to it's own question, tagged with Windows. Not sure what's right :)

Comment: Thanks and keep it here - good to have all info in one place. 

Comment: Thanks very much. In my case, I had to move this file to it `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` only then it worked. I didn't have GnuPG folder inside `AppData`, might help someone else.

Comment: For GnuPG 2.4.3 on Windows, I had to put `gpg-agent.conf` in my `AppData\gnupg` folder for it to work.

Answer (score 18):

Make sure to reload your gpg agent with `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye` after changing the config.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a comment or answer. Weird that it got upvote. It's not related to what the OP is asking. OP wants to have longer cache time for passphrase.

Comment: It is more like a comment but I couldn't write those when I wrote this answer. Also no matter how you change your config, you need to reload the agent or nothing changes.

Answer (score 4):

Since your problem is you need more or unlimited cache time for passphrase, then you can use `gpg-preset-passphrase` to cache your gpg password, and you will have unlimited cache time until the agent is restarted / reloaded. Read the documentation here:

`gpg-preset-passphrase`:

> Passphrases set with this utility don’t expire unless the --forget
> option is used to explicitly clear them from the cache — or gpg-agent
> is either restarted or reloaded (by sending a SIGHUP to it). Note that
> the maximum cache time as set with --max-cache-ttl is still honored.
> It is necessary to allow this passphrase presetting by starting
> gpg-agent with the --allow-preset-passphrase.

[Documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase.html#:%7E:text=The%20gpg%2Dpreset%2Dpassphrase%20is,with%20GnuPG%202%20and%20later.)

Example how to cache password using gpg-preset-passphrase utility in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
GPG_PRESET_PASS="/usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase"
KEY_GRIP=$(gpg --with-keygrip --list-secret-keys $KEY_ID | grep -Pom1 '^ *Keygrip += +\K.*')
read -s -p "[$script_name]: Enter passphrase to cache into gpg-agent: " PASSPHRASE; echo
$GPG_PRESET_PASS -c $KEY_GRIP <<< $PASSPHRASE
RETVAL=$?
if [ $RETVAL = 0 ]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "NOT OK"
fi
```

Comment: grep (2.5.1-FreeBSD) on MacOS (darwin19.6.0) doesn't support -P/--perl-regexp but perl does: `perl -lne 'print,$found++,exit if s/^ *Keygrip += +//; END {exit !defined $found}'`